# Gradient with respect to x of a matrix function

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Suppose I have the function:

$$F(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}2y^2 & 3x^4\end{bmatrix}$$

And I am asked to compute this:

$$\nabla_x F(x,y)$$

(gradient with respect to $x$ of the function $F(x,y)$).

How am I suppose to calculate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you'll unfortunately find frequently in multivariable calculus, notation is not fully standardized, and I can only guess at what $\nabla_x$ means. But if I had to guess, I'd say it's the partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ (i.e. differentiate with respect to $x$ while holding all variables other than $x$ fixed) which just applies coordinate-wise to vector-valued functions:
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 12x^3\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: I would say that your guess would be correct. I used your answer to my equation (Which is computing the action gradient for DDPG) and I got the expected output I was suppose to get. Since it works for me, I am marking this correct. Thank you for answering my question.